# Why does angle make geom_image points drift

Tags: r, ggplot2

why is the "angle" argument making the points from geom_image in a ggplot2 drift away from their desired position?

Demodata:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:N,
            y = 1:N,
            image = rep("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png", N),
            angle = seq(0, 45, length.out=N)
            )
```

Demoplot:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggimage")

p <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) 
for (i in 1:dim(d)[1]){
  di <- d[i, ]
  p = p + 
    geom_image(data = di, aes(image=image), angle = di$angle[1]) +
    geom_point(data=di)
}
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ggimage draws each image at (x,y) in a rotated viewport; it should instead draw within a rotated viewport placed at (x,y).

```
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")

grid.newpage()
grid.points(x = 0.5, y = 0.8, default.units = "npc", pch="+",gp=gpar(cex=5))
grid.raster(png::readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")), 
            x = 0.5, y = 0.8, vp = viewport(angle=45), height=unit(1,"cm"))
grid.raster(png::readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")), 
            vp = viewport(x = 0.5, y = 0.8, angle=45), height=unit(1,"cm"))
```